# Can I prevent phpDocumentor from adding timestamps to documentation, and thus keep my repository clean?

Tags: php, git, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I've just started using [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/) on an internal project.

I'm wondering whether there's a way I can prevent phpdoc from including timestamps in the documentation.

With timestamps, every time the documentation is updated, the git diff is riddled with lines like:

```
@@ -136,10 +136,10 @@
-   <div id="namespace-1177792219" class="accordion-body collapse in">
+   <div id="namespace-1212284973" class="accordion-body collapse in">

@@ -445,7 +445,7 @@
    Documentation is powered by <a href="http://www.phpdoc.org/">phpDocumentor </a> and authored
-   on June 2nd, 2016 at 05:14.
+   on June 2nd, 2016 at 05:33.
```

With over 30+ files of documentation, this makes the diff for a documentation update quite hard to read.

**Is there a way - eg. a `phpdoc.xml` configuration option - I can turn these timestamps off?**

The only reference in the [configuration documentation](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/configuration.html) to dates and timestamps is in relation to the log files, which I'm not using.

Alternatively, creative ways to exclude this from git commits - if that is even possible - are also welcome.